# Show that in a comb space any path from the point $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ must pass through the point $(0,0)$.

Tags: general-topology

So, I approached the proof by trying to show that if I take a path $f$ from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ and if $(0,0)$ does not belong to $\Im(f)$ then $f([0,1])$ will not be connected. But I am unable to use the right way of proving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that such a path passes through all points of the form $(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)},0)$ (i.e., the midpoints between successive "teeth"). If $f(t_n)=(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)},0)$, let $t_\infty\in[0,1]$ be a limit point of the $t_n$. What can you say about $f(t_\infty)$?

Comment: Well, $f(t_\infty)$ will be (0,0). But how do I prove rigorously that the path passes through the midpoints between successive teeth?

Comment: @mary: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thnx.. got it now.